# Can an External JS file circumvent the same-origin policy?

Tags: same-origin-policy, external-js

I'm currently creating an API that requires the user to include an external javascript file from my server. However, the file requires that it calls an AJAX function (located in the external javascript file) that pulls the user's API data from my server and outputs it on to their webpage.

Will I run into trouble regarding the same-origin policy?
If so, are there any alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Not really as it's presented as a specific circumstance.

Comment: Never-the-less, several solutions offered on that question will satisfy the question here.

Comment: After further reviewing the solutions, they don't seem to answer my question.

Comment: Are you sure?  What about the "Cross Origin resource sharing" method, or the 'JSONP' method prevents you from using them?

Comment: I meant my question about using the external file. I just got my answer though. I used another server to test the communication between the two. I'll look into these alternatives now. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx to understand how Same Origin Policy works.

Answer (score 0):

The policy is simple a same-domain policy, so, you shouldn't have a problem.  For example, most webmasters load jQuery from Google's CDN, as they should, and they still use jQuery's Ajax with it.  Hope that answers your question!  (Sometimes I am completely oblivious to the actual question, so... hope it helps)